# Flow cannot be deleted

Tags: visual-workflow

[image]I have a flow which is referring another flow.

Everytime I try to delete the flow, it throws the following error:

Error: This flow definition is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again.  Flow Trigger

Error page on clicking Flow Trigger link:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: That "Flow Trigger" on the right is a link. It will take you to the dependency.

Comment: It dies not. just gives an error page.

Comment: Really? What does that second error page look like?

Comment: updated the new screenshot. Please check. Thank u fr your assistance

Comment: Delete the reference from the flow first and then delete the flow. Hopefully, it should work

Comment: Interesting, that doesn't usually happen. As BobGali mentioned above, you could try removing the reference to the second flow and see if that lets you delete first one. Otherwise, you could try using the metadata api to remove that second flow with destructiveChanges since it looks like you won't be able to do it in the ui. Otherwise, if neither of those things work, it looks like you would have to contact salesforce customer support to have them resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the flow(say A) is referenced in another flow(say B), update or remove the reference of Flow A in Flow B. This way,you will be able to delete the flow A.